# How to use Mysql Date function in doctrine dql zend framework

Tags: mysql, zend-framework, doctrine-orm, dql

I need mysql date function in order by as I only want to sort with date not dateTime.

```
 $dql  = "SELECT r FROM Entities\Reservation r ";
 $dql .= "JOIN r.lot l ";
 $dql .= "LEFT JOIN r.car c";
 $dql .= " WHERE l.id = '" . $lot->id . "'" ;
 $dql .= " AND r.complete ='1' ";
 $dql .= " AND r.cancelled=0";
 $dql .= " ORDER BY r.start DESC, c.is_disabled_person DESC";        

 $query = $this->getEntityManager()->createQuery($dql);
 $query = $this->getResult();
```

Comment: Have you tried `$dql .= " ORDER BY DATE(r.start) DESC, c.is_disabled_person DESC";`  Is there some reason that presents problems?

Comment: Yes I tried that but it gives me error "expectd end of string got ("